# Error when inserting data to Wordpress database. SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo

I am trying to make a code that can insert products in a WooCommerce installation (Wordpress). I keep getting this error, even tough the parameter count seems okay both in the database table (23 columns), query (23 columns) and values (also 23). I guess that something is wrong, but no matter how many times I check the code, everything seems fine to me.

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO wp_posts (ID,post_author,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_content,post_title,post_excerpt,post_status,comment_status,ping_status,post_password,post_name,to_ping,pinged,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_content_filtered,post_parent,guid,menu_order,post_type,post_mime_type,comment_count) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
              $sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlinsert);

              if($sth->execute(array(
                 "ID" => $id,
                 "post_author" => $post_author,
                 "post_date" => "NOW()",
                 "post_date_gmt" => "NOW()",
                 "post_content" => $post_content,
                 "post_title" => $post_title,
                 "post_excerpt" => $post_excerpt,
                 "post_status" => $post_status,
                 "comment_status" => $comment_status,
                 "ping_status" => $ping_status,
                 "post_password" => $post_password,
                 "post_name" => $post_name,
                 "to_ping" => $to_ping,
                 "pinged" => $pinged,
                 "post_modified" => "NOW()",
                 "post_modified_gmt" => "NOW()",
                 "post_content_filtered" => $post_content_filtered,
                 "post_parent" => $post_parent,
                 "guid" => $guid,
                 "menu_order" => $menu_order,
                 "post_type" => $post_type,
                 "post_mime_type" => $post_mime_type,
                 "comment_count" => $comment_count
              ))){
                 $contadorinsert++;
              }else{
                 $contadorerror++;
              }
```

I have checked several times that none of the values are NULL, because all the fields in the Wordpress wp_posts tables are set to require NOT NULL values. This is the `var_dump` of my `$post` array, which contains all the values I am sending to the database:

`/var/www/fs/plugins/importador_woocommerce/controller/importador_woocommerce.php:115:
array (size=18)
    'post_author' => int 1
    'post_title' => string 'SIME BRAVA SLIM 25BF ESTANCA NATURAL IONIZADA 8112500' (length=53)
    'post_content' => string '' (length=0)
    'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
    'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
    'comment_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
    'ping_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
    'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
    'post_name' => string '' (length=0)
    'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
    'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
    'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
    'post_parent' => int 0
    'guid' => string 'http://fs.local/?post_type=product&p=' (length=37)
    'menu_order' => int 0
    'post_type' => string 'product' (length=7)
    'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
    'comment_count' => int 0`

The Wordpress original wp_posts table has the following structure (with utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci encoding instead of ut8_general_ci for the newer versions of Wordpress):

my table structure :

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `ID` be AI?

Comment: and post date should be current time stamp?

Comment: And this way of works with named placeholders

Comment: How did you check that? I've revised the code several times and I am pretty sure that you are absolutely right. But for some reason my dumb eyes are keeping me stuck in this for a while today.

Comment: Can you post what are you sending in your variables and definition of your table columns? Compare each variable with column type ex. if you sending numbers as varchars and in DB are defined as integer etc.

Comment: Yes, ID should be an Auto Increment field. I've corrected that, thanks Option. I still have the same problem though, I guess that it must be a tiny error that prevents me from progressing. I have also tried to set my date fields as $post_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); instead of mySQL's NOW()

Comment: Technicaly the type of data that I am sending is correct for each column, JohnWayne. I've checked that several times.

Comment: @OriolA. can u remove the following in your query : `post_date
post_date_gmt post_modified ID` and then remove 4 of the question marks

Comment: then after that try with this `if($sth->execute(array($post_author,$post_content,$post_title,$post_excerpt,$post_status,$comment_status,$ping_status,$post_password,$post_name,$to_ping,$pinged,$post_content_filtered,$post_parent,$guid,$menu_order,$post_type,$post_mime_type,$comment_count))){
                 $contadorinsert++;
              }else{
                 $contadorerror++;
              }`

Comment: `post_modified` post modified should be null on insert as the post yet have not been modified, you should use that when you update

Comment: `post_date_gmt` this should be a default current timestamp... therefore shouldn't be part of your insert, make sure its inserted by default and is never null

Comment: ok after all this answers and comments, what the problem is you are facing is with extra values, try to print all the string values that you are passing and check whether they are inside single quote or double qoute or else mysql will treat them as different fields, i guess you are facing this problem

Comment: @Exprator Can you ellaborate more on this? Which are "the good quotes" in order for them to be treated as separated fields, one at a time?

Comment: see like you are passing $post_title, now if the title is somewhat like " this is a post ", but somehow the quotes are not there then it sql will take the 4 words as 4 different field, so thus i am saying try to print the variable you are passing to check the values are properly formatted or not

Comment: @OriolA. did you tried my suggestions [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387726/error-when-inserting-data-to-wordpress-database-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parame#comment75775554_44387726)

Comment: @masivuye-cokile Still getting the same error :( My array of values has 18 elements.

Comment: @OriolA.can you post your variables (what are you sending to DB)

Comment: @JohnWayne check the updated post with the var_dump of the array (after removing autoincrement ID and date fields).

Answer (score 0):

```
$currenttime= current_time( 'mysql' );
```

Place this  `$currenttime` rather than `now()` at `post_modified/post_modified_gmt`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the place where I am executing my code from is not a Wordpress installation. I am trying to insert data on a Wordpress database from an external PHP application, not in Wordpress code.

Comment: Then remove the double quote from now , just place now()

Comment: Removing the quotes from NOW() causes the script to crash because it's a MYSQL function, not a PHP one, and therefore PHP says that my function is undefined.

Comment: @SachinIngale `Now()` is undefined function in php

Comment: then pass this date("Y-m-d H:i:s")

Comment: That is what I have been doing so far. I've also been told to remove the date fields. Might have to keep them to avoid MySQL from inserting whatever it wants.